# V-toolip on other template [vuetify]

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have a v-data-table all set with 5 columns.
I'd like to have a text appearing as the v-tooltip component.
But since it's in one template, I can't use the tooltip on it because v-tooltip also requires the `<template #activator="{ on }">` . Does anyone know how to do it ?

Here's what one of my column looks like in the code.

```
<template #item.title2="{ item }">
  <div class="ellipsis news">
    <a
      target="_blank"
      v-if="item.file != ''"
      class="links1"
      :href="item.file"
      v-on="on"
    >
      <span style="color:white"> {{ item.title }} </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</template>
```

Ideally, I would put the v-tooltip around it but then I get this message.

[image]

My v-data-table looks like this. I'd like the 'news' and 'actors' fields'details when I hover.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's not a second `#activator` slot you can simply place the `<v-tooltip>` element between the column item slot and the tooltip's activator slot

```html
<template #item.title2="{ item }">
  <v-tooltip bottom>
    <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <div class="ellipsis news" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
        <a
          target="_blank"
          v-if="item.file != ''"
          class="links1"
          :href="item.file"
        >
          <span style="color: white"> {{ item.title }} </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </template>
    <span>Im A ToolTip</span>
  </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

Your code snippet doesn't show a second `#activator` slot being used, but if you do find yourself in that situation where you have to deal with nested activators, there is actually documentation about this on the [v-menu](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#activator-and-tooltip) page